# Parse JSON from file using PHP from objects/arrays

Tags: php, json, file, parsing, decode

I get the following output using print_r in php of my decoded JSON:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [assignments] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [assignmentid] => 1
                    [grades] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [userid] => 3
                                    [attemptnumber] => 0
                                    [timecreated] => 1484244192
                                    [timemodified] => 1484244203
                                    [grader] => 2
                                    [grade] => 85.00000
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I want to get the value for [grade] => 85.00000 and store it in a variable. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Update the question with what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
$var = $obj->assignments[0]->grades[0]->grade;
```

Comment: Then, you can mark this as the accepted answer, so people searching for a similar problem knows the answer. ;)

Comment: How do I loop through the decoded JSON if there were multiple objects in the grades array. Each time storing the value in a variable/array

Comment: `$grades = array(); foreach($obj->assignments[0]->grades as $gradeInfo){ $grades[] = $gradeInfo->grade; }`

Answer (score 0):

Use `true` as second parameter of `json_decode()` to decode it to array and then you have to loop over your result.

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($data['assignments'] as $row) { 
    foreach ($row['grades'] as $grade) {
        echo $grade['grade'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why convert a perfectly good object into an array? It is just not necessary